# Labeling 2 variables in scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, labeling

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#install.packages("ggrepel")
library(ggrepel)
#Code
mpg %>%
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class == '2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = ifelse(Color == '2seater', '2seater', "")),
                   force_pull = 0, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

in the above code if I want to add another label for 'compact' how would I change the code please, so i would like 2 labels- one for compact and 2seater

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `case_when` where you have used `if else`. [Although you could use an `ifelse` inside another `ifelse`. But I find `case_when` cleaner.]

But have a look. Aren't there too many labels? Why not just leave it color coded?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)

#Code
ggplot2::mpg %>%
  mutate(Color = case_when(
    class == "2seater" ~ "2seater",
    class == "compact" ~ "compact",
    TRUE ~ "other"
  )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(
    label =
      case_when(
        class == "2seater" ~ "2seater",
        class == "compact" ~ "compact"
      )
  ),
  force_pull = 0, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "gray")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `case_when()` method proposed by MarBlo, you can also subset the data while specifying the layer. Upside is that is shorter to write, downside is that the labels don't repel the unlabelled points. As mentioned by MarBlo, ggrepel protests that there might be too many labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggrepel)

mpg %>%
  mutate(Color=ifelse(class == '2seater','2seater','Other')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy, colour = Color)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = class),
                  data = ~ subset(., class %in% c("2seater", "compact")),
                  force_pull = 0, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
#> Warning: ggrepel: 31 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider
#> increasing max.overlaps
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>